# Regex with any term optional and in any order (javascript or java)

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I have a string like this "%d-%m-%Y" , **any of these terms can be in any order, and the dash can be another string** (%x).
I want to get the result as : "%d %m %Y" . 
I baked a straightforward regex and it doesn't seam to work if I make the terms optional :
 (Do this in chrome console:)

```
"%d-%m-%Y HH:%i".replace(/.*?((%Y|%m|%d)?.*?(%Y|%m|%d)?.*?(%Y|%m|%d)?).*/, "$1    $2   $3    $4")
```

I have this (%Y|%m|%d)? as optional 3 times  with .*? (non greedy anything) between them.

if I run the above line of code the output is :

```
"%d    %d       "
```

If i remove the optional marker from (%Y|%m|%d)? then the expression works as expected.
I need those terms to be optional.
Can someone explan to me what is going on  with the optional markers, and can this type of regex be done?

Comment: With optional you mean `"%d-%m"` would be legal as well? I assume `"%d-%d"` would not be legal and thus I'd say regex are not the right tool here - I'm not sure you could do this with Java's regex engine (or any other as well), and even if, it might be quite hard.

Comment: yes, "%d-%m" is legal, and "%d-%d" cannot happen ..

Comment: So, you require all 3 but only once, in any order and with anything in between?

Comment: Yes all 3 2 or 1 in any order and with anything in between . (I am now analysing your answer , it doesn't replace with " " in javascript )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your requirements but maybe a 2-step approach would work:

1. extract the permutations of `%d.*%m.*%Y`, e.g. using `temp = input.replaceAll(".*(%(?:d|m|Y).*%(?:d|m|Y).*%(?:d|m|Y)).*", "$1")`
2. replace the content between `%d`, `%m` and `%Y`, e.g. using `temp.replaceAll("(?<=%(?:d|m|Y))(.*?)(?=%(?:d|m|Y))", " ");`

Java example:

```
String input ="xx %Y-%m-%d xx";    
String temp = input.replaceAll( ".*(%(?:d|m|Y).*%(?:d|m|Y).*%(?:d|m|Y)).*", "$1" );
String output = temp.replaceAll( "(?<=%(?:d|m|Y))(.*?)(?=%(?:d|m|Y))", " " );

System.out.println(output);   //results in "%Y %m %d"
```

Notes: 
- This requires 3 components, i.e. `%d-%m` would not match.
-  `"%d-%d"` would still be allowed, checking that with regex would be hard.

**Update**: the following expression should allow for 1-3 components: `.*?(%(?:d|m|Y)(?:.*%(?:d|m|Y)){0,2}).*` in step one.

Comment: My regex also works  for non optional terms , but as soon as I make the terms optional (to have only %Y-%d for ex) then it misteriously breaks

Comment: I think my best solution is to create 3 regexses : one with 1 term one with 2 terms and one with 3 terms . Before I apply the correct regex I can do and indexOf %Y,%m and %d and count how many of them there are and if there are 2 apply the regex with 2 arguments..

Comment: @OvidiuBuligan please see my update. You'd still have to count whether there are multiple occurences of a single term though.

Comment: For maintenance purposes I think it is better to use the 3 cases (1,2,3 terms) because it is more understandable and also works in javascript .(your regex doesn't work in in javascript)