# Simple RegEx wierd result

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace all occurences of 'S' (capital S) with '.sss' :

For example the following line doesn't even contain a capital S in it and it still replaces a lot :

```
 "MM/dd/yyyy EEEE hh:mm aa".replace(new RegExp('S*', 'g'),'.sss')
```

The result is :

```
".sssM.sssM.sss/.sssd.sssd.sss/.sssy.sssy.sssy.sssy.sss .sssE.sssE.sssE.sssE.sss .sssh.sssh.sss:.sssm.sssm.sss .sssa.sssa.sss"
```

Don't have any Ideea ..

(to test this example just copy and paste it in chrome or firefox dev tools on any page and run it)

Comment: It should be `new RegExp('S','g')` or just `/S/g`, `*` matches anything.

Comment: Why are you using the asterisk *(0-1)* quantizer? Just match one.

Comment: I also want to match trailing SSSS's

Comment: Use `new RegExp('S+', '.sss')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `*` matches 0 or more, so you are also matching the occurence of 0 "S", means it matches every position, where "S" is not ahead, or behind ([see it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?37m3i)). Change it to

```
S+
```

[see it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?37m3l), or even only "S".

`+` [Quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) matches one or more.

Comment: Yes that was It!  don't know why I didn't see it . Usualy when i write  X* it is in the middle of an more complex expression and is enforced by the other parts of the expression

Answer (score 1):

The `*` quantifier is matching between `0` or **more** times here, as many times as possible. Therefore in this case it is matching at every character position of your string. See [what I `mean`](http://regex101.com/r/pZ4gG6).

You are looking for the `+` quantifier meaning match `1` or more times.

Although since your using the `g` modifier (global) you can simply use the following:

```
"MM/dd/yyyy EEEE hh:mm aa".replace(/S/g, '.sss')
// => "MM/dd/yyyy EEEE hh:mm aa"
```

Comment: just so you know I have another old regex question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117764/regex-with-any-term-optional-and-in-any-order-javascript-or-java

Comment: I feel underestimated a bit but any detailed explanation is good for the community

Answer (score 1):

Use `RegExp('S+', 'g')`

because * matches zero or more times the previous character.

"+" matches the character at least 1 time but also more.

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = str.replace(/S/g,".sss");
```

Try this. [Use this link](http://regexpal.com/)